# invalid input syntax for integer pgsql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have just started with postgresql. I have a json object in table. There is a numeric value in the json object in which i want to add a number and assign it to other integer. This is how I am doing

```
declare  
 total_votes integer;
....
select result into poll_result from polls where id = 1;
total_votes =  (select poll_result::json#>'{total_votes}'::integer + 1);
```

But this is showing

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "{total_votes}"
LINE 1: SELECT (select poll_result::json#>'{total_votes}'::integer +...
```

poll_result has the data like

```
{
    "yes": 1,
    "no": 0,
    "total_votes": 1
}
```

and when I try to print total_votes using

```
RAISE NOTICE '%',poll_result::json#>'{total_votes};
```

It prints 1.

even I have tried

```
total_votes =  (select (poll_result::json#>'{total_votes}')::integer + 1);
```

But the error

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type json to integer
LINE 1: ...ELECT (select (poll_result::json#>'{total_votes}')::integer ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator `#>` gives a json, while `#>>` gives a text and you need the second one:

```
select (poll_result::json #>> '{total_votes}')::integer + 1
```

or

```
select (poll_result::json ->> 'total_votes')::integer + 1
```

See [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)